# MSAL Android :Missing required tokens of type: {0} while acquireToken

Tags: android, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am integrating the [MSAL 2.2.1](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android) into the android app.

1. I have registered the app in the Azure b2c portal.
2. generated the signatures and added them to the Azure b2c portal.
3. got the login page upon trying to acquire the token.
4. Upon successful login, MSAL redirecting to our app.
   But not onto the onSuccess but onto the onError with the following stack trace.

onError:Missing required tokens of type: {0}

```
2021-10-05 03:16:21.310 9573-9573/com.test.msal W/System.err: com.microsoft.identity.client.exception.MsalClientException: Missing required tokens of type: {0}
2021-10-05 03:16:21.310 9573-9573/com.test.msal W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.identity.client.internal.controllers.MsalExceptionAdapter.msalExceptionFromBaseException(MsalExceptionAdapter.java:51)
2021-10-05 03:16:21.310 9573-9573/com.test.msal W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.identity.client.PublicClientApplication$18.onError(PublicClientApplication.java:1903)
2021-10-05 03:16:21.310 9573-9573/com.test.msal W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.identity.client.PublicClientApplication$18.onError(PublicClientApplication.java:1894)
2021-10-05 03:16:21.311 9573-9573/com.test.msal W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.controllers.CommandDispatcher.commandCallbackOnError(CommandDispatcher.java:447)
2021-10-05 03:16:21.311 9573-9573/com.test.msal W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.controllers.CommandDispatcher.access$800(CommandDispatcher.java:82)
2021-10-05 03:16:21.311 9573-9573/com.test.msal W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.controllers.CommandDispatcher$3.run(CommandDispatcher.java:429)
2021-10-05 03:16:21.311 9573-9573/com.test.msal W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
2021-10-05 03:16:21.311 9573-9573/com.test.msal W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
2021-10-05 03:16:21.311 9573-9573/com.test.msal W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
2021-10-05 03:16:21.311 9573-9573/com.test.msal W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7697)
2021-10-05 03:16:21.311 9573-9573/com.test.msal W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2021-10-05 03:16:21.311 9573-9573/com.test.msal W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
2021-10-05 03:16:21.311 9573-9573/com.test.msal W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
2021-10-05 03:16:21.311 9573-9573/com.test.msal W/System.err: Caused by: com.microsoft.identity.common.exception.ClientException: Missing required tokens of type: {0}
2021-10-05 03:16:21.311 9573-9573/com.test.msal W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.providers.microsoft.microsoftsts.MicrosoftStsOAuth2Strategy.validateTokensAreInResponse(MicrosoftStsOAuth2Strategy.java:638)
2021-10-05 03:16:21.311 9573-9573/com.test.msal W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.providers.microsoft.microsoftsts.MicrosoftStsOAuth2Strategy.validateTokenResponse(MicrosoftStsOAuth2Strategy.java:577)
2021-10-05 03:16:21.311 9573-9573/com.test.msal W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.providers.microsoft.microsoftsts.MicrosoftStsOAuth2Strategy.validateTokenResponse(MicrosoftStsOAuth2Strategy.java:87)
2021-10-05 03:16:21.311 9573-9573/com.test.msal W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.providers.oauth2.OAuth2Strategy.validateTokenResponse(OAuth2Strategy.java:174)
2021-10-05 03:16:21.311 9573-9573/com.test.msal W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.providers.oauth2.OAuth2Strategy.requestToken(OAuth2Strategy.java:166)
2021-10-05 03:16:21.311 9573-9573/com.test.msal W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.controllers.BaseController.performTokenRequest(BaseController.java:294)
2021-10-05 03:16:21.311 9573-9573/com.test.msal W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.controllers.LocalMSALController.acquireToken(LocalMSALController.java:170)
2021-10-05 03:16:21.311 9573-9573/com.test.msal W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.commands.InteractiveTokenCommand.execute(InteractiveTokenCommand.java:67)
2021-10-05 03:16:21.311 9573-9573/com.test.msal W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.commands.InteractiveTokenCommand.execute(InteractiveTokenCommand.java:39)
2021-10-05 03:16:21.311 9573-9573/com.test.msal W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.controllers.CommandDispatcher.executeCommand(CommandDispatcher.java:381)
2021-10-05 03:16:21.311 9573-9573/com.test.msal W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.controllers.CommandDispatcher.access$000(CommandDispatcher.java:82)
2021-10-05 03:16:21.311 9573-9573/com.test.msal W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.controllers.CommandDispatcher$4.run(CommandDispatcher.java:584)
```

And my request code looks like below:

```
application.acquireToken(requireActivity(),arrayOf("openid", "offline_access"),object : AuthenticationCallback {
```

And I have these permissions granted in the Azure b2c portal.

But still unable to get the token. Can someone help in fixing this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

I have fixed this problem by using my client-id as Scope type:

```
public static List<String> getScopes() {
    return Arrays.asList(
            "your-client-id-here");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to passing invalid scope types, or omitting a required scope value.  In my case, the auth response included an `id_token` and `refresh_token`, but not an `access_token`.

The error message provided by the library is not helpful and I've filed an issue here: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-common-for-android/issues/1674